# Forbidding some specific cases of indirect enum in swift

Tags: swift, enums

How can I ensure that some indirect cases of my enum are forbidden?

For instance, here is my type:

```
enum PerkCard : Hashable {
    case add(Int)
    case mult(Int)
    indirect case roll(PerkCard)
}
```

I can create instances of cases, but some should not be allowed (you can't have roll of roll cards)

```
let c1 = PerkCard.add(1)
let c2 = PerkCard.roll(.add(1))
let c3 = PerkCard.roll(.roll(.add(1))) // Forbidden
```

I don't see any way to prevent it on creation. Is it just possible?

Thanks in advance.

**PS:** I know I can add a `check` method that would do the job, but that's not the question.

**PPS:** I also know I can design this example with this kind of `struct`

```
struct PerkCard : Hashable {
    let value : Int
    let kind : Kind
    let roll : Bool

    enum Kind {
        case add, mult
    }
}
```

But that's not the point either.

Comment: Cases of an enum are part of its public API. The best way to achieve what you want is to wrap your enum in a struct, and only expose the parts you want to be public.

Comment: Ok... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Swift supports polymorphic or extensible enums, or constrainted subtyping.

So I'd do this by splitting the enum in two rather than have a recursive enum:

```swift
enum A {
    case add(Int)
    case mult(Int)
}
enum B {
    case a(A)
    case roll(A)
}
```

it's slightly less convenient in a way (as you have to write `.a(.add(5))` instead of just `.add(5)`) but it's easy enough to create simple helpers to generate `add` and `mult` values.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to know how to do it with a single indirect enum type. The example I gave was really simplified...

Comment: I don't think you can. In fact I don't see how you'd do that even in languages with more expressive type systems.

Comment: Thanks then, that's what I feared... I thought I could override some kind of `init` to throw an error, or maybe something else...

Comment: You can always validate things at runtime if you can't change the structure, but I don't think there's a hook on variant initialisations either so you'll have to swap the variant constructors for actual factory functions.